# Refreshing a HTML page with Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, websocket

I'm working on an Automation project using TestNG. I have created a Listener that updates a HTML file every time there is a test passed/failed/skip etc.

The only issue I have is that if I want to see these changes I have to manually refresh the HTML page.

Is there any code I can use within Java to automatically refresh a HTML page whenever a change is made to it or just refresh every second once the program is running?

EDIT: Seen that its mostly javascript this is done through so some advice on how to integrate JS into my Java class would be beneficial also, thanks.

Comment: May be you can do a periodic AJAX call from HTML itself. If something new found, update the content of the page.

Comment: you could use some automatication with Selenium or one timeout on JS to auto refresh the page

Comment: Thanks @Kartic I will look into it.

Comment: @cralfaro I was trying to go down that route but everytime I was refreshing I was refreshing the browser my tests where being run in and not the browser my HTML page was open in.

Comment: Or websocket, with this you can do in real-time updates ;-)

Comment: @ToniVillena That was mentioned to me previously before, have you any useful links? What I have created at the moment is very basic. I want to make it as high-tech/feature rich as possible.

Comment: @Colin Here is a good example :-) https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/

Comment: Thank you @ToniVillena I will look into it :)

Comment: And Mozilla's MDN is a good site to see websocket in JS too:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: Maybe you should share the code you already have. It will be easier to advise you and I am sure the testng community will be interessed by your listener.